# Difference between implementing RAID 0 and attaching multiple EBS Volumes on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs, raid

What is difference between implementing RAID 0 and just attaching multiple EBS Volumes on AWS EC2? Both *seem* to just sum the performance (?).
Any other operational differences or use case scenarios, even cost - **RAID-0 vs Single Volume.**

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly create a RAID with EBS. AWS Actually has a [guide on how to configure RAID 0](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ebs/latest/userguide/raid-config.html) (which is the recommended one) with 2 or more EBS volumes.

RAID 0 arrays on Amazon EBS boost file system performance by spreading I/O across multiple volumes. They're best for high-performance needs. Adding volumes increases throughput and IOPS, but **performance is limited by the slowest volume**, and **losing any volume means losing all data**. The array's size and bandwidth are the combined sizes and bandwidths of its volumes. For example, two 500 GiB io1 volumes with 4,000 IOPS each form a 1000 GiB RAID 0 array with 8,000 IOPS and 1,000 MiB/s throughput.

To prevent catastrophic data loss, it is recommended to backup your RAID volumes with [EBS multi-volume snapshots](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_CreateSnapshots.html)

Answer (score 1):

Adding multiple EBS volumes on EC2 without creating a RAID does not "sum" the performance. With individual volumes simply mapped to separate mount points, you would only get the performance of a single volume (the volume mounted to the path you are writing to) during any write operation.

Comment: OK, so summation  happens only with RAID - the documentation (AWS at least) does not state that in any way. So without RAID, I simply get the additional storage capacity on the new volume - that is what I would also think. Any other pros/cons of RAID vs a Single larger volume (meeting the performance needs)

Comment: An EBS volume is just added to your server as another disk volume. AWS doesn't say what happens after that, because after that it is up to the operating system software that you have chosen for your EC2 instance (and your chosen configuration for that software) to deal with the volumes. It's really no different from adding another hard drive to your desktop PC.

Comment: Yes I agree - it all depends on the configuration that is implemented. But, the point here was, there are specific examples (in documentation) that refer to increasing performance by adding additional volumes - they don't mention (in any way) that you will have to to actually setup RAID to achieve the higher performance.  Any other pros/cons of RAID-0 vs Single large server.

Comment: You should link to specific documentation in your question, if you have questions about that documentation. You made no mention of that documentation in your question at all, so I'm not sure how "the point here" could be about some specific examples in documentation that you didn't reference at all.

Answer (score 1):

Both RAID are increase storage performance. But there are some key differences and considerations to keep in mind:

**RAID 0:**

1. Utilizes data striping for improved performance. It means, this can improve read and write performance since multiple disks can work in parallel to retrieve or store data.
2. No fault tolerance. It means, if one disk fails, all data stored across the entire array may be lost.
3. It Requires configuration. This involves additional management overhead.
4. No additional cost beyond disks.

**Attaching Multiple EBS Volumes:**

1. There is No striping. Each volume operates independently.
2. No fault tolerance across volumes. Isolated failures.
3. Simple attachment, and possible managed through AWS tools easily.
4. Incurs additional cost per volume.

**Use Case:**

***RAID 0:*** Where performance is critical and fault tolerance is not a concern, such as high-performance computing, data analytics, and temporary data storage where data integrity is not crucial.

***Attaching Multiple EBS Volumes:*** Where fault tolerance is important, or when you need to scale storage capacity without necessarily maximising performance, such as web servers, databases, and file servers.

Comment: So, if I can get the desired performance from a Single Volume I should prefer that rather than multiple volumes RAID-0 ?

Comment: Yes,  if a single volume can deliver the desired performance, it's preferable to implement RAID 0 with multiple volumes. RAID 0 should only be considered if performance requirements cannot be met by a single volume alone.